# Fragments with recordmydesktop

Tags: screencast, recordmydesktop

I tried to record an Screencast wih gtk-recordmydesktop. The Sound Quality is great but I get a lot of fragments in the Video. Its comes if I refresh an area like the browser windows.

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

The settings are the same after the installation. Nothing changed.

Answer (score 1):

I have the solution for your problem.

When you start recordmydesktop from the terminal you have perfect recordings.

Open the terminal copy and past this command:

```
recordmydesktop --delay 10 --fps 20 --channels 1 --device hw:1 -o filenameofvideo
```

- delay of 10 seconds
- frames per second 20
- channels 1  (microphone)
- `--device hw:1` that is my external microphone you might have to change it `--device hw:0`
- -o is overwrite existing file
- filenameofvideo is the desired filename

Happy recording!

Check the results on my [YouTube Channel](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCldwrSuNLjLzRiOdqLj_7Ew/%22Youtube%20Channel%22)

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same results with gtk-recordmydesktop also. These video distortions are called artifacts. You may wish to try [Kazam](http://www.twm-kd.com/category/linux/kazam/) instead. It has worked a lot better for me.

[image]